# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null [LARAVEL]

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I don't know what is wrong my code,please help I am almost finish it. I am using Laravel 7 btw

I received this message when I wanna update the phone number/email/password

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null (SQL: 
update `users` set `email` = ?, `password` = 
$2y$10$KZBGY4BFJIWzgh2wGhQ3yuZivuzo..MOLs2ahAYbXpecOUZsZ/nvC, `users`.`updated_at` = 2022-01-26 
21:46:50 where `id` = 7)
```

Here is my update function

```
public function updateStaffDetails(Request $request, Staff $staff, User $user)
{
    //$name = $request->input('stud_name');
    $staff->update([
        'staffPhone' => $request['staffPhone'],
        'staffEmail' => $request['staffEmail'],
        'staffPassword' => $request['staffPassword'],
    ]);
    $user =Auth::user();
    $user->update([
        //'name' => $staff->staffName,
        'email' => $staff->staffEmail,
        'password'=> Hash::make($staff->staffPassword),  //bcrypt($staff->staffPassword)
    ]);
    $staff->user_id = $user->id;
   $user->save();
    $staff->save();

     return redirect()->route('home',Auth::user())
    ->with('success','Staff details updated successfully.');

}
```

as you can see the Staff table will be copied to the users table once it is updated but the email from Users table is null...

here is my routes (because I think the problem is my route but i am not sure )

```
//admin show details
Route::get('/showDetailsAdm', 'StaffController@showDetailsAdm')->name('admins.showDetailsAdm');
//admin update
Route::put('/admins/updateStaffDetails', 'StaffController@updateStaffDetails')->name('admins.updateStaffDetails');
```

here is the picture of the column Staffs and Users `user_id` is FK from Users table

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNo42.png)

Comment: because `$request['staffEmail']` is `null`?

Comment: @Wilson yes it is null but the email is there in database.. i think there is something wrong with my routes.. i have two users, admin and staff T.T i still don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your route must be like

```
Route::put('users/{user}/staffs/{staff}/update','StaffController@updateStaffDetails')->name('admins.updateStaffDetails');
```

Then you can get **$user** and **$staff** in your controller. Now, $staff isn't null so you can get email from it.

While calling to this route you need to pass **user_id** and **staff_id** as shown below:

```
route('admins.updateStaffDetails', [$user_id, $staff_id] )
```

Comment: i dont understand the $user_id,$staff_id..

Comment: You need to pass id of admin as user and id of staff to the route that I mentioned above.

Comment: hurmm it says undefined user_id

Comment: for user_id you can pass **"auth()->user()->id"**
Also can you please share image from where you are calling this route

Comment: do you mean where the data i got from?

Comment: share image from where you will call update route to update your data

Comment: @leabelle You should take a look at method injection on Laravel. Further information https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#method-injection